# can I use webclient.uploadvalues()

Tags: c#, webclient

I used `WebClient.UploadValues()` to fill in a form with good success.  I am trying to use it for a url with a query string but it isn't working.  I ended up using `WebClient.DownloadData(String URL)`, is there a better way to do this?

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/?method=a&fill=yes
```

Comment: A better way to do what? It is not clear what the actual issue you are having is.

Comment: No. Uploading form encoded data is different from putting things on the query string. The data is transmitted differently. You'll have to construct those query strings yourself.

Comment: Thanks, if you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it.  I suspected that was the case, but I wasn't 100% sure and wanted to make sure I figured out the best way to do it before I use it over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Uploading form encoded data is different from putting things on the query string. The data is transmitted differently. You'll have to construct those query strings yourself.

Comment: question: how is it transmitted differently? is it sent in the body? header? or how? thanks

Comment: @user441365: You should post that as a question, rather than as a comment to a 5 year old answer.

Comment: Jim Mischel why is that?